# At work my Word 2016 tells a .docx corrupted. LibreOffice 6.1 opens it well at home. docx file format exist for long. Word 2016 doesn't handle it?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, microsoft-word-2016

At work, I'm trying to open a `.docx` file I received.
My *Word 2016* tells that it is corrupted. But when I try at home with *LibreOffice 6.1* it opens well.

Has the *Word* file format changed since the publication of Word 2016 for some `.docx` files?
What else might happen?

Comment: Microsoft tools are incredibly wary of even slight corruption or deviation from the "standard" format. Renaming a `docm` to `docx` will give an error "found a problem with its contents" as will modifying some of the actual contents of the file outside of Word. Word is being defensively picky about the file format, LibreOffice does not care as much about the precise format so long as it is "close enough" to get a reasonable approximation of the original.

Comment: the same thing happens with Adobe Acrobat when the same PDF files can be opened "without problem" in other PDF readers like Chrome, Foxit or Firefox. My project deals with processing tons of files every day so I've seen so many cases like that. It's just the different levels of tolerability and recoverability of each software

Answer (score 0):

Different tools implement different ways to manage files of the same standard (.docx in this case)

This mean that some of them might consider the same file as corrupted, while it's fine for the other.

Have you tried saving the file in Libre Office and opening it after in Word?

Answer (score 0):

The file format of .docx has not been modified. What software is this file generated from?

In some cases, Word really cannot open files generated by other applications.

In addition, the Open and Repair command might be able to recover your file.

Click File > Open > Browse and then go to the location or folder where the document is stored.

[image]

Click the file you want, and then click the arrow next to Open, and click Open and Repair.

[image]